# How UIApplicationDelegate enforce its `window` to be `internal` and not `private`, but okay when the name is change to `door`?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a storyboard less iOS App as below. I need to manually assigned the `window?.rootViewController` etc.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    internal var window: UIWindow? = nil

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let viewController = ViewController()
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
        window?.rootViewController = viewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

Looking at the code, I thought that since `window` is not override, so I can do as below; i.e. to make the `window` not optional. However the below code is not working. Apparently, `window` need to be as part of the `AppDelegate` member.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let viewController = ViewController()
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
        window.rootViewController = viewController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

With that, I then try out the below same to my first code, except that the `window` is now `private` instead of `internal`. I got a complaint `Property 'window' must be as accessible as its enclosing type because it matches a requirement in protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'`

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    private var window: UIWindow? = nil

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let viewController = ViewController()
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
        window?.rootViewController = viewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

I try to look into the code of `UIApplicationDelegate`, and can't find out which code make the `window` required to be public.

It is interesting to me that if I change the `window` name to another name, e.g. `door`, it works regardless of `internal` or `private`, as shown in two set of code below.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    internal var door: UIWindow? = nil

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        door = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let viewController = ViewController()
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
        door?.rootViewController = viewController
        door?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

And it also works when `door` is `private` as below. No complaint.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    private var door: UIWindow? = nil

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        door = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let viewController = ViewController()
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
        door?.rootViewController = viewController
        door?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

So I'm curious, what code in `UIApplicationDelegate` enforce to ensure `window` is `internal` and not `private`, and why doesn't it applies to when I change to `door`?

Comment: Because door is not declared in the UIApplicationDelegate protocol.

Comment: Thanks @matt. Thanks explains. I just saw the `optional var window: UIWindow? { get set }` in the code. Then it is strange that if I use `door`, it still works setting the `viewContorller` What's the implication of using `door` instead of `window`? Would that impose any issue further down the road? If ti does, that's risky, as there's no warning stated.

Comment: Not for your code, but if you _were_ using a storyboard then the runtime would need the window property. Plus other code might expect to be able to access the application’s delegate’s window. Otherwise, no, you’re right, it’s optional! https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623056-window